# Is System Sequence Diagram part of Analysis or Design?

Tags: uml, modeling, sequence-diagram, ooad

I'm wondering if System Sequence Diagram (SSD) belongs to design part or analysis part?

Comment: According to which method or standard? UML itself does not define the terms analysis and design.

Comment: OOP  for software developing

Comment: OOP is only about programming, not about analysis or design. Where did you find the term "System Sequence Diagram"?

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by System Sequence Diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [System Sequence Diagram (SSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_sequence_diagram) is be a special type of [UML sequence diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html) that intends to document for one specific use case the the sequence of exchanges between the system under consideration and the outside actors.

It is not a standard UML diagram, but build upon such diagrams.  The book "System analysis and design in a changing world" seem to have popularized this approach, but I could find articles dating back to the early 2000' (like [this](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1765179) or [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4071317_Linking_UML_models_of_design_and_requirement)).

The above mentioned book places the SSD in the analysis activities.  The reason is that [analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_analysis) is about understanding the requirements, which often start with use-case. The SSD is then a fine-tuning of this analysis.

However, one could argue that it's part of the design activities, since the use case are the requirements, but how these requirements are addressed through a sequence of exchanges is already the start of the [design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_design#Logical_design) of a solution, exactly as when you start to sketch an UI: more than one SSD could satisfy the needs and you have the choice.

So the answer depends on the purpose for which you're using the model.

*My own point of view is that you're already drafting a solution, so it should be design,  unless you do some reverse engineering of an existing application, or your client has very detailed requirements*

Comment: Actually there's no SSD defined in the current UML specs. And an IT paper from 2000 (unless it's from one of the IT Popes) can likely be compared to stone engravings.

Comment: @ThomasKilian That's what I tried to say with the statement "It is not a standard UML diagram" ;-)  About the stone engravement, interestingly the sequence diagrams (i.e. Booch's former interaction diagrams) are around since 1994 and their principles have not fundamentally changed since then.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for.

Comment: So, that's what I meant with the Popes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating a little on Christophe's answer:

I would add that *analysis* and *design* are two highly intertwined activities, so you would probably see these SSDs in both contexts and it would be perfectly fine and acceptable. Use Cases, those that involve a system, are necessarily a design artefact (they are a design of what the *system does* in relation to external actors) although you can of course see that same thing as a pure *analysis* output (telling you what the system is *required* to do). These things are very hard to separate. The point may seem philosophical (it is somewhat), but it is useful to think in these terms.

When you see people creating "Login" Use Cases you can bet they already stepped into *pure design*, in other words: functional decomposition. In analytical terms the state of a User being *logged in* is a **constraint** on a Use Case, not a Use Case itself. Having a Use Case called Login therefore represents only a design choice (incidentally, if you see this in contexts where there is a division of responsibilities between the people performing analysis and design, then you'd do well to consider it an analysis fail: the analyst is essentially designing the system and that's not their role). Analysts sometimes use Use Cases to model layers of requirements that relate only to business processes, usually referred to as "Business Use Cases", that don't involve any *system* per se. But the origins of Use Cases from 20-odd years ago was in the system space.

Comment: Login can only be a use case of a user authentication system, but I strongly agree, that in a normal system it is a precondition a user has to ensure in case she wants to use the system successfully. By the way, use cases have been introduced on the OOPSLA 1987. So they are now more than thirty years old (and we still don‘t agree what they are ;-) I would also consider a use case “relating to business processes” to be a normal use case with a business system (e.g a firm) as subject. It’s just a matter of what my modeling focus is: the business or the software.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer From requirements to systems. That will still fail in eternity...

Comment: @AxelScheithauer Agreed

Comment: @ThomasKilian Login being a constraint is what I indicated? In analytical terms, that is. I'm not sure what you mean here...?

Comment: Was it 30 years ago? Blimey, time flies.

Comment: "...the state of a User being *logged in* is a **constraint** on a Use Case, not a Use Case itself". I think we're on the same page on this. And I do agree yes about such a UC deriving value in an authentication system context.

Comment: Uh, oh. That was misleading. I guess that needs re-phrasing. Let me do a dummy edit to take back the down vote and I'l think about a different wording for that.

Comment: I hope the changed text is ok with you. You might do a dummy edit too to remove my face from the edit area and we can remove the discussion here too ;-)

Comment: Nah that's cool mate, happy to accept the edits, and happy for your name to appear if you are. Communication via text is hard -- in the words of Mark Twain "I didn't have time to write a short letter, so I wrote a long one instead".